# ADT in C Defining Functions

Tags: c, adt, typedef, abstract-data-type

So I'm trying to teach myself some ADT concepts. So I have created 3 files

- a main.c
- a prototypes.h and
- a functions.c

The problem I have is that I'm not sure how I would define the function in the prototypes. I tried `typedef`, but that for data types rather than functions. I know I have to use the preprocessor `#define` method.

But I'm not sure how to go about defining (#define) a new type for a function.

Is it: #define fileRead() = FREAD

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A function prototype is simply the function header without the body, as a declaration.

Example:

```
void hello(void);
```

is the prototype for a function named `hello` which takes no argument and returns no value. If this is put in a header file, then all sources including the header file will be able to call the function.

The function does of course have to be *defined* in one source file:

```
void hello(void)
{
    /* Some code... */
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you understood my question.

Comment: @user1704227 I'm not sure you understand what `#define` does or what function prototypes are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really mean, but if you wanna use a function pointer, things are looks like this:

```
typedef void (*func_ptr) (int, int);

func_ptr(512, 1024);
```

maybe you should say it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what u want

#define FREAD fileRead

and u can call

FREAD();